# Imageresizer License key was issued in the future

Tags: imageresizer

We just purchased a performance license, when adding it to the config section, and running /resizer.debug we get the following error:

resizer configuration(Warning): License key was issued in the future; check system clock: ourdomain

License keys
You do not have any license keys installed.

System time is fine. Perhaps the generation of license key is in US timezone? We just have to wait?

Comment: Or you could contact the company and ask them.

Comment: Your server may be displaying the correct local time, but have the wrong time zone and time value.

Comment: It shows the correct time for the timezone it's located in: GMT+1 and is set to. Either way, waiting a few hours obviously worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting a few hours rectified the issue.