# ImageResizer debug page telling that license key was issued in the future (red dot remains)

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer

I encountered the same problem as mentioned in [Imageresizer License key was issued in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577726/imageresizer-license-key-was-issued-in-the-future), but after waiting for 2 days nothing has changed for me.
The errors/warnings shown on the debug page are the following:

```
resizer configuration(Warning): License key was issued in the future; check system clock: immoigel.de

resizer configuration(Error): No license found for domain immoigel.de - features installed: R4Performance or R4DiskCache
```

I'm currently in Timezone UTC+01:00 and the installed version of ImageResizer is 4.0.5.942.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Email support@imageresizing.net and we'll help you figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, IIS and ASP.NET failed to pick up Web.config changes.

Always try `iisreset` if configuration errors remain after you think you've fixed the problem.